# Do we have or should we have a guide for making good questions?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395198/how-to-prove-that-a-set-of-connectives-arent-adequate) was made and I asked the usual:

> You should provide more info: What have you tried? What are the definitions? What book are you reading?

The user replied me by saying that he tried to do something about it - but he was unable to understand. I tried to help by suggesting some heuristics that could be interesting in posing questions but I believe that the competence of  guiding people on how to make useful/interesting questions is lacking in me.

When I was new in the site, I remember of not having the skill to isolate my problem in a precise way - I'm not a professional at it today, but I believe I got a little better with time.

So is there a official guide made by MSE to help people to formulate their questions a little better? If this guide does not exist, shouldn't we make it? For the time being I guess I should suggest [this webpage](https://mathoverflow.net/howtoask) on Math Overflow. Although the MO guide seems to be complete:

- It's not official on MSE;
- Some users shouldn't even know about the existence of MO. I guess it's counter intuitive to think about searching for how to make a nice question in another website, we can't expect them to think: *I want to make a good question, I'll search the technique for it on MO!*
- We would have to repost the link for every new question that isn't following the given criteria. As it is the case with the PSQ's - the community should always repeat: *Welcome to MSE! Do not post PSQ's! Live long and prosper!*

Comment: +1 The MO is certainly a good starting point. I'm all for having something similar.

Comment: +1 to the question, but I'll bring up another reason we can't just adopt the MO guide. It is written with a different audience in mind: MO audience is mostly mathematicians, graduate students and truly outstanding undergraduates. A Math.SE guide would need to be something that a non-precocious 13-year-old can read and understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes!**

For now, there is the [good homework question thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803). But it's limited, and we don't really want to imply that every question that needs some reworking is a homework question.

I brought up this point in the cursive remark following my PSQ template [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9202/43351) but nobody has gotten round to creating such a thread.

There has been an initiative for collecting snippets in the past, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588). But it hasn't been put into one, coherent policy yet.